# Running an operation on one column based on content from another column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the negative value of rows in column `'nominal'` where the corresponding value in column `'side'` is equal to 'B'. I don't want to lose any rows that are not converted. I've tried this below but getting raise `KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])`

```
df[-df['nominal']].where(df['side']=='B')
```

Comment: Could you post a sample dataframe? It's challenging to walk through your example without it. Also when you mention "trying to convert the negative values", what are you trying to convert them to? Are you trying to make them `'B'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this:

```
df.loc[ ( df.side == 'B' ), 'nominal' ] *= -1
```

Comment: What prompted you to add this as an answer given that it is identical to the answer I had already provided below?

Answer (score 6):

Just use both conditions in a boolean index with `&`.

```
df[(df.side == 'B') & (df.nominal < 0)]
```

or if you intend on modifying,

```
df.loc[(df.side == 'B') & (df.nominal < 0), 'nominal']
```

**Example**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(side=['A']*3+['B']*3, nominal = [1, -2, -2, 2, 6, -5]))
>>> df 
   nominal side
0        1    A
1       -2    A
2       -2    A
3        2    B
4        6    B
5       -5    B

>>> df.loc[(df.side == 'B') & (df.nominal < 0), 'nominal'] = 1000

>>> df
   nominal side
0        1    A
1       -2    A
2       -2    A
3        2    B
4        6    B
5     1000    B
```

This is a very standard way for filtering data in Pandas that you'll come across often. See [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in the Pandas docs.

---

**Update**

For your updated problem description, we can just use the augmented assignment operator `*=` to multiply our desired values by -1.

```
df.loc[(df.side == 'B'), 'nominal'] *= -1
```

**Example**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(nominal = [1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3], side=['A']*3 + ['B']*3))

>>> df
   nominal side
0        1    A
1        2    A
2        5    A
3        3    B
4        5    B
5        3    B

>>> df.loc[(df.side == 'B'), 'nominal'] *= -1

df
   nominal side
0        1    A
1        2    A
2        5    A
3       -3    B
4       -5    B
5       -3    B
```

Comment: my issue is a bit more tricky. All my values in column 'nominal' are positive numbers. I only want to convert to negative values if the corresponding column side = "B"

Comment: @obabs I provided an update to my answer. It would have been helpful if that had been more clear in the original question :)